# Calculating DIY lens hood

Tags: diy, lens-hood

There are [Free printable cardboard lens hoods](http://www.lenshoods.co.uk/) for various lenses but not for my [FUJIFILM X30](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x30/specifications/) camera.

How do I calculate its shape/dimensions? (It can be either petal or ring shaped.)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important number here is [angle of view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view). That tells you where the rectangular pyramid of light that gets to the camera sensor intersects with the edges of the lens hood.

The common "petal" lens hood shape comes from this pyramid. You can imagine in the design of such a hood that they build an overly-long round lens hood, then project this pyramid out from the lens. Where the two intersect, they cut that part away, then round it off a bit. They probably cut it back a bit, too, so there is no danger of [vignetting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting).

You can calculate angle of view (and more!) using [ƒ/Calc](http://fcalc.net/), a free tool you can download and use on your Mac or Windows computer, or use [online](http://fcalc.net/online/).

So, if you can find another lens hood made for a lens with the same angle of view, you're partway there.

The real trick is that all of the lenses that site has got hoods for are going to be quite a bit larger in diameter than your lens. You can't just cinch up the hood, because that will distort the petal shape. You could do that with a round one, though.